# Can employers know employee age given a W-9 form?

Tags: united-states, taxes, privacy, w9

The W9 doesn't specifically ask for age info, but given the other things like name, address, and TIN, would it possible (and legally viable) for the employer to perform some more research on you? This can include using TIN verification software or using some reverse people search given that they know the address and name.

Comment: With your name and address, a Google search can often find your approximate age. Whether or not it's legal to do that, I don't know, but I wouldn't be surprised if it isn't.

Comment: If by TIN you mean social security, a rough approximation of when and where you were born can be derived just from that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about personal finance. It might be better suited for [law.se], given it is asking about legality.

Comment: I'm pretty sure most businesses are essentially legally required to know your age due to special regulations for under-18 workers...

Comment: @keshlam true if your were born before 2011 when SSNs were randomized. My twins, born in 2012 have very different SSNs.

Comment: Most folks born in 2011 or later haven't yet gotten to the point of asking for workplace advice. There are a few exceptions, but most folks in that age group also aren't worried about who knows their age, at least not unless they're trying to get away with something.

Answer (score 8):

Because the [W9 form](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw9.pdf) doesn't ask for your date of birth, they wouldn't have a method of looking up your age.

If you are a w-2 employee you will complete a [W4 form](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf), which also doesn't have your date of birth. But they will also collect the data and proof of your ability to work in the US via the [i-9 form](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-9-paper-version.pdf). The i-9 form does include your date of birth.

There could be a state form, or a background investigation form that does require you to supply your date of birth. That form could be required regardless of your 1099/W-2 status.

Comment: +1. W9/W4 won't help in that, but I-9 most definitely will.

Comment: Your employer may also want to know your age for benefits purposes -- insurance, retirement, and the like.